# How can I get this SPECIFIC element in selenium in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

UPDATE:
So thanks to the voted answer it displayed some information not the right information, it shows `0kb out of 100` and when in the inspect element console if doing `console.log($0)` then the item would be displayed in console how do I fetch this

I want to create a python 3.x programme that gets my stats off of [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and [easybase](https://easybase.io/) using selenium. The issue I have come across already is that the element does not have a specific class name and the text widget isn't just a

tag nor a  tag. Here is a screenshot of the html of [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)  [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnshn.png), and this is the code that I used

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("github")
element.click()
login = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
login.send_keys(email)
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.send_keys(passwordstr)
loginbtn = driver.find_element_by_name("commit")
loginbtn.click()
getbandwidth = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[1]/div/section/div/div/div/dl/div/dd')
print(getbandwidth.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getbandwidth = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//dd[@class='tw-text-xl tw-mt-4px tw-leading-none']")
```

You can use this to grab the first xpath with that class. Below does the same but if you want to index other elements with similar classes.

```
(//dd[@class='tw-text-xl tw-mt-4px tw-leading-none'])[1]
```

Normally we use webdriver waits to allow for the element to become visible.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
getbandwidth = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//dd[@class='tw-text-xl tw-mt-4px tw-leading-none']")))
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//dd[@class='tw-text-xl tw-mt-4px tw-leading-none']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72) pulls this error

Comment: Add a small wait before that since you used .click() prior.

Comment: No problem accept my answer. I'll add a webdriver wait answer.

Comment: sadly the outcome is not what I expected though as you can see on the screenshote, i have used 19mb of bandwith and the output produced states 0kb quite confused

Comment: Use the second line of what I posted and try that. It gets the first value with that xpath.

Comment: still throws 0kb, if this helps, in dev tools on chrome in the console, when doing ```console.log($0)``` as it states then it produces this value but when trying to get the attributes value it comes back as none